# "Going to go" or not?

Tags: grammaticality

I have been corrected by a person more educated than I for my use of *going to go* as in a statement of intent. Is my critic correct?

Comment: "I'm going to go to the store in a few minutes" is perfectly proper and idiomatic (at least in the US).

Comment: Without examples, it’s hard to say, but it’s quite possible your use is ok. Many legitimate uses of that phrasing can be readily produced.

Answer (score 1):

It is technically correct, but using 'go' in two of the three words in the sentence is repetitive. Sounds better if you say *Going to attend/join/be there* etc.

Comment: In print it's the kind of thing some people avoid, but in speech there's no problem, because there aren't two /go/'s. It's pronounced /'gənə'go/ and it's perfectly normal colloquial English.